# Why does `xgboost` find such an unbalanced split in my data?

Tags: boosting

I'm using `xgboost` for regression. The data and the `python` script used for analyzing the data are uploaded 
[here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1y5x8qL_xpjQI0Bu5F_D_NKwAzAxvTU9X?usp=sharing). The `data` file is a pickled `python list` that can be loaded with `pickle`.

The dimension of each instance is $96$, and there are $11450$ instances in total. The target values are in the range $[-1, 1]$. Because both the feature dimension and the number of instances are pretty large, I will not show the statistics of the dataset.

For the purpose of regression, here is a piece of code I used (which you can view the full version from the link above)

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
model_exact = XGBRegressor(max_depth = 5, 
                           n_estimators = 1,
                           slient = False, 
                           min_child_weight = 1, 
                           tree_method = 'exact')
model_exact.fit(x_train, 
                y_train, 
                eval_set=eval_set,
                eval_metric="mae",
                early_stopping_rounds=30)
```

As you can see from the code, I'm using only one `gbtree` whose `max_depth = 5` for regression.

After I train the model, I found that the root node of the very first tree divides the whole dataset into two very unbalanced parts.

Here is the result:

```
min_child_weight = 1
tree_method = 'exact'
max_depth = 5 --> I only show the first level

booster[0]:
0:[f25<0.985234857] yes=1,no=2,missing=1,gain=0.314697266,cover=9160
    1:[f12<0.95821929] yes=3,no=4,missing=3,gain=0.226806641,cover=9159
    2:leaf=0.00314080133,cover=1
```

On the other hand, if I set `min_child_weights = 5`, `xgboost` divides the whole dataset only once

```
min_child_weight = 5
tree_method = 'exact'
max_depth = 5

booster[0]:
0:[f84<0.935616255] yes=1,no=2,missing=1,gain=0.127441406,cover=9160
    1:leaf=-0.0499953292,cover=9155
    2:leaf=-0.0249112509,cover=5
```

Similar result is obtained when I set `tree_method` to `approx`.

Why `xgboost` cannot evenly divide this dataset? Is there some kind of flaw in this dataset?

The reason that I ask this question is `xgboost` overfits severely on this dataset, I don't know whether it is a result of the unbalanced split that I described.

Comment: The result returned by any algorithm without knowledge about the data & parameters is meaningless. You need to give us more details.

Comment: @Tim♦ I have modified the post. Because I thought the code I uploaded explains the question pretty much, so I didn't include too much details in the post...

Comment: I think this is a misunderstanding of how `xgboost` works; `xgboost` looks for splits which cause large reductions in the loss, not balanced splits. This is described in more detail in the paper and documentation.